# ObjectUtils.defaultIfNull() for null check

Tags: java, java-8

```
car.setName(  entity.getThingType() != null ? entity.getThingType().getTypeName() : null);
```

How can we re-write this statement using `ObjectUtils.defaultIfNull()`

I tired below way, seems some issue

```
car.setName(ObjectUtils.defaultIfNull(entity.getThingType(), null).getTypeName());
```

Comment: Please could you be more specific than "seems some issue"? Did you get a compile-time error (and if so, what), or an exception (and if so, what) or not the behavior you expected (and if so, what did you expect and what happened)? Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for suggestions on how to write good questions.

Comment: Why would you pass `null` as the second argument to `defaultIfNull`? The point of that method is to return the second argument if the first argument is null. If the default value you pass it *is* null, you're just doing `entity.getThingType()` with extra steps.

Comment: There is no `ObjectUtils` class in the standard Java API. Assuming that it does what the name suggests, i.e. return a default value for `null`, your attempt to use it here is pointless. You are trying to substitute `null` with the default value `null`. So the result is not different to `entity.getThingType() .getTypeName()`, getting a `NullPointerException` when `getThingType()` returned `null`.

Comment: Consider changing the implementation of `getThingType()` so it never returns null.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you can solve by using `Optional<?>`

```java
String nullName = null;

String name = Optional.ofNullable(nullName)
                      .map(<doSomething>)
                      .orElse("Default value in case of null");
                   // .orElseThrow(NullPointerException::new);
                   // .orElseThrow(CustomException::new);
```